# A subgroup of the multiplicative reals

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to find a subgroup $H$ of $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ such that for any $x,y\in \Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, 
$xy^{-1}$ is in $H$ implies that $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, and vice versa. 
How would I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider what it means for $x$ and $y$ to have the same sign by thinking of the ordering that's on $\Bbb{R}.$ You can assert that if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, say positive, then $x>0$ and $y>0.$ You should then ask yourself, if you take $x$ and $y,$ both with negative sign, what happens to the quantity $xy^{-1}=\frac{x}{y}?$ What is the sign here?

The real question is, what can you say about $\Bbb{R}_{>0}=\{\alpha \in \Bbb{R},~ \alpha >0\}?$ Is this a suitable choice of $H?$

Comment: It seems to be, since x/y would be positive. However, how would I approach this in reverse to examine this? I'm not sure what xy^-1 being in H can show...

Comment: Are you familiar with the one-step subgroup test?

Comment: I am not... a quick read gives me that it says ℝ>0 would work as a subgroup of H, since x,y are of ℝ>0 and xy^-y is in H. But also, since the group is Rx, isn't this equal to ℝ>0?

Comment: Is there anything in $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ that is not in $\Bbb{R}_{>0}?$

Comment: RIGHT sorry, negatives just totally slipped my mind.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If yes, please consider an upvote. If your question is answered entirely, then please click "accept answer"

Answer (score 0):

Vice versa?  Do you mean that whenever $x,y$ have the same sign then $xy^{-1} \in H$.  Then for any positive real $r$, $r$ and $1$ are the same sign and $r1^{-1} = r\in H$.

For any negative real $s$ then $s$ and $1$ are opposite signs and $s*1^{-1} = s \no \in H$.

So $H = \mathbb R^+ = \{r \in \mathbb R| r > 0\}$.